# How to set secured path settings using Python

Tags: python, django

I need one help. I am uploading file into folder and for that I have set constant in `settings.py` file using Python. I am explaining my code below.

> settings.py:

```
FILE_PATH = os.getcwd()+'/upload/'
```

> views.py:

```
report = Reactor.objects.all()
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.csv'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
    with open(settings.FILE_PATH + filename, 'w') as csv_file:
        file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        response_writer = csv.writer(response)
        file_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
        response_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Status', 'Date'])
        for rec in report:
            if rec.status == 1:
                status = 'Start'
            if rec.status == 0:
                status = 'Stop'
            if rec.status == 2:
                status = 'Suspend'
            file_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
            response_writer.writerow([rec.rname, status, rec.date])
    return response
```

Here I need the secured file path to upload the downloaded file into folder using Python and Django.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing to the file row by row? I would make a list or dataframe first & then write that to the csv.

```
import pandas as pd

#make your dataframe by adding your rows to a list
df = pd.DataFrame(list)   
df.to_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: Where I will add it.

Comment: Actually I need to prevent path traversal attack.

Comment: I'm not sure the implications on preventing path traversal attacks (since that is about how you name your files & where you store them), but instead of opening a file as "w" and writing to it, go through your report that you want to save to the file and you can write your rows as a list of dict objects and make a df from that, and then save that df to a csv based on a filename you give it.

Comment: File name is `unique id` and I am storing it inside `upload` folder.